# What's the quickest way to get the President or equivalent authority on the phone? Life depends on it!

Tags: communication, artificial-intelligence, internet, cybernetics

Scenario.

You have 30 minutes before a deadly cyber-virus will infect everything connected to the internet. The national security level is already high due to recent events. In this future, majority of humans are biologically connected to the web so this virus will directly harm them if delivered.

After contemplating numerous scenarios, you and your team determine shutting down the power grid is the only way to prevent this. You would attempt to blow it up yourselves, but the grids are heavily guarded and those attempts would fail.

Whats the quickest & most convincing way to get authority on the phone who would believe you and take action?

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE Little Bro.  Sounds like a great movie!  Unfortunately, it's a question where you're asking us to write the story for you.  Please check out our [tour] and [help] to learn more about writing questions that are on topic.  Feel free to stick around and answer questions or ask others.

Comment: @DonQualm LOL! got it thank you!

Comment: @Cyn will do thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just turn the internet off? The electrical grid powers more than just the internet.

Comment: *"The president"* covers a multitude as, contrary to what some people think, there are lots of people with that title.  Typically presidents (or in many countries the relevant office would be Prime Minister or e.g. Chancellor) are politicians and faced with making a huge decision quickly they will more often than not fail miserably to act responsibly for the common good.  They almost certainly cannot do what you describe - it would cripple their own ability to respond to the crisis.

Comment: @StephenG Any number of chief executives almost certainly can't do what the OP is asking about regardless of desire. They'd have to ask the proper department head, who would have to tell the proper supervisor, who would have to write up a plan of action, which would... (There's probably an environmental impact assessment in there somewhere, too.)

Comment: I don't understand why you and your (powerless) team are sitting around "contemplating numerous scenarios" while the clock is ticking. You call the firefighters when you smell smoke, not after tedious analysis. Do your contemplation *after* notifying 911 (or equivalent), and while they are connecting in a higher echelon of emergency operations center (they can generally do that).

Comment: You won't succeed.  Lets look at a practical case:  One of the Twin Towers engineers realized the towers were going to fall and tried to sound the alarm.  (Obviously, his knowledge couldn't have averted the collapse but it could have reduced the death toll.)

Comment: The electrical power grid *isn't* guarded, actually - it's actually quite fragile, and IIRC it's been listed as a potential vector for terrorist attacks by the US government.

Comment: Usually, if there is the possibility to threaten the population to this degree, there is a department for handling it. Call them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**By having authority**

You need to be in a position of authority first otherwise people won't believe you and even then they might not. A random person won't be believed because people make hoax calls all the time.

At the end of the day, the person in charge usually doesn't have a clue. Just imagine trying to have a cyber-security chat with Donald Trump. No offence but it's not something he knows anything about. You need to convince Homeland Security and hope like hell they can get the sign off or they just decide to do it due to the time constraints.

Without authority, you need simple undeniable proof and hope like hell you can work up the chain of command in time.